# How to implement analogue of exit() functions? -std=c99

Tags: c, exit, c99, termination

I'm writing a university project. Writing in standard C99. One of the requirements is the lack of *exit();* function. Is it possible to implement a similar function?
I tried to make a function that calls *main* with a minus *argc* to detect exit. It was a stupid attempt, because the first *main* continues.

Just the description of the project specified that the scores will be reduced for the use of exit by exit().I understand that it asks me to code running through pointers and returns an error in the return values ​​of the function. I'm more interested in the practice. Only for myself.

Comment: Why the C++ tag? This is a C99 question...

Comment: "Writing in standard C99. One of the requirements is the lack of exit();" - then it's not standard C99.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the requirement. Are you saying that your environment doesn't include `exit()`? Or are you saying that you are constrained to never call it?

Comment: `man exit`, which version do you want to implement?

Comment: on linux? how about embedded asm code to do system call. like 
        mov eax,1            
 mov ebx,0            
 int 80h

Comment: *"One of the requirements is the lack of exit(); function."* -- What does that mean? Can you show us *exactly* how the requirement is phrased?

Comment: H2CO, Writing it in the standard, but is also considered a mistake to use *goto* and *scanf with %s*...

Comment: If you mustn't use `exit()`, there's always `abort()`. (Not really serious.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I *think* you misunderstood the requirement: They probably said something like `do not use exit()`. This does not mean you are supposed to implement your own `exit()`, quite to the contrary: they probably mean that the only exit-point of your program shall be the end of your main-function (or a return-statement within the main function) which is considered good programming style.

Comment: Just the description of the project specified that the scores will be reduced for the use of exit by exit().I understand that it asks me to code running through pointers and returns an error in the return values ​​of the function. I'm more interested in the practice. Only for myself.

Comment: @MarkBirger: Exactly what this answer said. You should design your program such that errors propagate up (via return statements) all the way back to the main function, instead of calling `exit`.

Answer (score 1):

`exit()` is a system level facility that you can't implement on your own without knowing how the operating system implements it (Linux? Windows? embedded system?) works.  As Daniel Fischer mentioned, you could call `abort()` which will basically do the same thing that exit will do and quit the program.

There are other "hacks" to get your program to abort without calling `exit()` explicitly, but these are just hacks and should not be used in production code.

1. Create a C++ function with C linkage and throw an exception

   extern "C" MyExit() { throw std::exception(); }
2. Call `signal()` with SIGKILL
3. Call `abort()`
4. Write some assembly code to unwind the call stack until it gets to the function that called `main` and insert the return value in to the proper return register and go from there. I don't think you can do this in pure C, as the ABI is not accessible directly. But at least this would be only method that doesn't involve the operating system (just the ABI).